# Calculating this quotient?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

What is the quotient of the algebraic Groups $GL_n$ by $Sp_n$ equal to?  I was conisering a different example and would use the universal property to establish it, but I wasn't certain what it should equal to a-priori.

Comment: What's $Sp_n$? do you mean $SL_n$?

Comment: $Sp_n$ (the symplectic group) is not a normal subgroup of $GL_n$ so $GL_n/Sp_n$ is not a group.  Do you mean to ask what $GL_n/Sp_n$ is as a variety?  If so I have no idea.  There might not be an easier description of that variety than saying "it's $GL_n/Sp_n$".

Comment: Ya I was wondering if it was isomorphic to a familiar variety (not alg. grp; oops lol)